# SDKによるRTCを使用したDeep sleep制御

Tags: spresense, arduino

省電力化のため、RTCによる Deep Sleep (または Cold Sleep) の制御について調べています。
Arduino IDEでは、LowPower Library API を使うことで、RTCを使ってDeep Sleep(または Cold Sleep)から起動(boot)することが出来ますが、SDKでは、up_pm_sleepにタイマー制御までは実装されていない様です。

SDK 環境で RTCタイマーを使用した Sleep制御の方法がございましたら、ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

(Arduio IDE の LowPowerClass を SDK側に取り込めたら良さそうなのですが・・・）

Answer (score 1):

Arduinoのソースコードを見る限り、RTCアラームを設定してからスリープしているだけのようです。見よう見まねでSDKでも試してみたら同じ動きになりました(当然といえば当然ですが)

以下の方法で、SDKのNutShellコマンドを使って動作を確認しました。

アラームサンプルを有効にしてビルド：

```
$ ./tools/config.py examples/alarm
$ make
```

NutShell上で、`alarm`コマンドで10秒のアラームタイマーを設定した後に`poweroff`コマンドでDeep Sleepすると、10秒後にウェイクアップして再起動します。

```
nsh> alarm 10
alarm_daemon started
alarm_daemon: Running
Opening /dev/rtc0
Alarm 0 set in 10 seconds
nsh> poweroff

NuttShell (NSH) NuttX-7.22
nsh>
```

Cold Sleepも同じく10秒後に起動できました。

```
nsh> alarm 10
nsh> poweroff --cold
```

単純にコマンドベースで確認してみましたが(これはこれで超便利)、
examples/alarmのソースとboard_power_off()関数の組み合わせで実現できると思います。
以上、参考になれば。

Comment: ご回答いただき有難うございます。
早速 alarmサンプル + poweroff を試してみたいと思います。
Deep Sleep 時はおそらくRTCの電流が見えるはずなので、その妥当性を確認してみます。